# JavaMelody and Spring

Tags: java, spring, java-melody

I have setup a rest service using the guide provided STS at: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I am at the beginning of the development but I want to make sure I have the right tools in place to measure the performance.

Key Performance Indicators I am interesting are:

- HTTP Request counter
- HTTP Request rate over a configurable period of time
- HTTP average latency
- And more

At the end i am interesting to gather statistics like here: http://ruleoftech.com/2013/monitoring-java-ee-application-with-javamelody

I failed to find any documentation that describe the steps involved for doing such things. The JavaMelody documentation at: https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide talks about copying the relevant jars in WEB-INF/lib but AFAIK there is no equivalent in Spring or at least in the way I am using it. I am not an expert in Spring.

I am looking for help on how to set this up.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Add java melody dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
<!-- javamelody-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.54.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add the monitoring spring context to your Application class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:net/bull/javamelody/monitoring-spring.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Use the "@MonitoredWithSpring" Java melody annotation to monitor your spring object:

```
@RestController
@MonitoredWithSpring
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();


    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How we can do that on xml based config ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell how you are "using" Spring but what I quickly looked at the STS guide for rest service it manages dependencies (jars) with Gradle or Maven and provides examples for both. The Rule of Tech example uses Maven ([as shown in JavaMelody docs](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#1._Jar_files)) to get the JavaMelody jars (to WEB-INF/lib) so you can follow the article to configure JavaMelody statistics for your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [javamelody spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter) which is a simpler solution for spring-boot 2.

Add javamelody spring-boot-starter dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.76.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And you are done (no need to import the monitoring-spring.xml resource and no need to add annotations to controllers).

For spring-boot 1 or to check the latest version, see [doc](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter).